# Is it possible or how to extract message string from binarized list?

Tags: list-manipulation, image-processing, ocr

Given message copied from [Silvia's profile page](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/17/silvia), a binarized list could be found bellow.

```
lst = Uncompress@
   "1:eJztk8ENwzAIRUkHyA5ZqdfeMkC6/605Vl8Gg8EykUD6imMb8/hxjvP7vl5EtN/\
63NpKpVIpqSgBg4XzKbwzvP6PJ/Baa2BvxMxzea1caV2al3zQnId7pHqS1yPsEkPPa8/\
Yk4c8MzmwjuSNtydp3DsHg/PMwov7o74/ntni4f6nSAbuXcPK8YzyYqy+\
16u8tnrmYYnq07LOee3pKcJrzX3XrHPnjdaz/\
if47NVqsWl4tBrJmalsPJF9ZegNYzVPKZ9+c/YGIg==";
```

or output is

```
lst // TableForm // TeXForm
```

> $\tiny{
> \begin{array}{ccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc}
>  1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 &
>    1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
>  1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 &
>    1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
>  1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 &
>    1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
>  1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 &
>    1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
>  1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 &
>    1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
>  1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 &
>    0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 &
>    1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
>  1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 &
>    1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
>  1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 &
>    1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
>  1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 &
>    1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
>  1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 &
>    0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
>  1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 &
>    1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
>  1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 &
>    0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
>  1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 &
>    1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
> \end{array}}
> $

at first, I tried appy `Total` and `FromCharacterCode` to pick up words.

```
FromCharacterCode/@(Total/@lst)
```

but
got sth meaningless chars.

> {"[", "[", "[", "X", "V", "(", "9", "2", ";", "<", "2", "Y", "U", "["}

so I gazed fixedly at the `Output list`, I found the message hidden in those `0`s' layout, and then an image was made for eyes vision.

```
lst /. {1 -> ""} // TableForm // Rasterize[#, ImageSize -> Large] &
```

> [image]

However, I cannot read the right `chars` from the image directly via eyes.
so I wonder is there methods to solve it automatically from the binarized list?
`TextRecognize` does not work in this case.

If any `Mail Address` be extracted, please replace `@` to `AT` to avoid disturbing the owner. Thanks!

@Silvia, I feel lucky to read your posts on [snowflake](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/235291),[boot logos](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1580817) and [BSpline](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1580817) demos, all impressive. Thanks for leaving a compressed message on your profile, I'd ask this question on how to extract message by MMA codes. If it bring you trouble, please let me know, I shall revise it ASAP.

Answer (score 3):

One method might be to use ArrayPlot to construct an image, and then use character recognition to decode the message.

[image]

(It's still not bot-readable, so I did not disguise it.)

Edit:

I think our 10^15 synapses are better at text recognition than my laptop:

[image]

```
TextRecognize[image2]

"(* wyemgm Em" *)
```

Comment: `lst // ArrayPlot // TextRecognize // 
 StringReplace[#, {"E" -> "AT", StringTake[#, -3] -> ".com"}] &`

Answer (score 0):

The original binarized list could be taken by `ImageData`.

```
str = "hello,world";
lst2 = Rasterize@"hello,world" // Binarize // ImageData;
lst2 // TableForm // TeXForm
```

> $\tiny{
> \begin{array}{ccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc}
>  1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 &
>    1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
>  1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 &
>    1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
>  1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 &
>    1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
>  1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 &
>    1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
>  1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 &
>    1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
>  1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 &
>    1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
>  1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 &
>    1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
>  1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 &
>    1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
>  1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 &
>    1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
>  1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 &
>    0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
>  1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 &
>    0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
>  1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 &
>    0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
>  1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 &
>    1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
>  1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 &
>    1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
>  1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 &
>    1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
> \end{array}}
> $

or compress it as

```
Compress@lst2
```

> "1:eJztlz0OgzAMhYPUvWfgBukxKpWFIzAgdeoA91cZkSDo+QdCHC9PIEWxnc9+\
>   gXb49eMzhDA9Fvl8p3ns1m/\
>   vZnl4udpQZ2tXna1dTbKNJ0SLG5WvtKfy2mMGtjvxVVfaU2drV89ni7gE1Ul02Wp5OC9z3\
>   vngdxO1doxtqg4kvjxryT6Sjt/2dWpnPDp+\
>   nmq1kz0Z6VqtjryeLUJPwlbXR65iq5v1fdjyps7Z5mOL/4GVxZZy31LP8tiTcfem+\
>   jzvSw7ZjVe7vJd5tWNza1sljl2MVscWn+3itTq2Fekf3wxX0w=="

or using `ArraryPlot`

```
ArraryPlot[lst2]
```

> [image]

Now I get an idea if the binarized list or image could **be divided to probable pieces**, a rasterized lib might be used to restore these chars.

```
pchr = CharacterRange[" ", "~"];
blst = Binarize /@ (Rasterize /@ ptn)
```

> [image]

then replacment `plib` could be

```
plib = Thread[blst -> pchr]
```

> [image]

If this method validate, it's better than using `TextRecognize`, but I no idea how to get through.:(

**Update1**
To count `0`s might help.

```
tmp = ((# /. {1 -> ""} & /@ (ImageData /@ blst)));
```

and get new replacements

```
newplib = Thread[DeleteCases[#, 0] & /@ ((Count[#, 0] & /@ Transpose@#) & /@ 
      tmp) -> pchr];
Partition[newplib, 3, 3, {1, 1}, {}] // TableForm // TeXForm
```

> $\small{
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  \{\}\to   & \{3,3\}\to ! & \{1,3,3,2\}\to \texttt{"} \\
>  \{2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2\}\to \# & \{4,4,8,4,4\}\to \$ & \{2,3,7,6,3,2\}\to \% \\
>  \{1,7,5,4,7,4,1\}\to \& & \{2\}\to ' & \{6,2\}\to ( \\
>  \{3,8,2\}\to ) & \{1,2,4,4,2,1\}\to * & \{1,1,1,1,1,1\}\to + \\
>  \{1,4,1\}\to , & \{1,1,1,1,1,1\}\to - & \{2\}\to . \\
>  \{1,3,3,3,2,1\}\to / & \{6,4,4,3,6,2\}\to 0 & \{2,2,8,1,1\}\to 1 \\
>  \{2,3,3,3,4\}\to 2 & \{1,3,3,3,5\}\to 3 & \{1,3,3,2,8,1,1\}\to 4 \\
>  \{5,3,3,3,4\}\to 5 & \{5,3,3,3,5\}\to 6 & \{1,2,3,3,3\}\to 7 \\
>  \{5,5,3,4,6\}\to 8 & \{4,3,3,3,6\}\to 9 & \{4\}\to : \\
>  \{1,6,3\}\to ; & \{1,2,2,2,2,2\}\to < & \{2,2,2,2,2,2\}\to = \\
>  \{2,3,2,2,2,1\}\to > & \{1,5,2,2\}\to ? & \{3,3,6,4,4,6,4,3\}\to @ \\
>  \{2,3,4,2,5,4,2\}\to \text{A} & \{8,3,3,3,5\}\to \text{B} & \{6,3,2,2,2\}\to \text{C} \\
>  \{8,2,2,3,6,3\}\to \text{D} & \{3,3,3,3\}\to \text{E} & \{2,2,2,2\}\to \text{F} \\
>  \{6,4,2,3,6\}\to \text{G} & \{8,1,1,1,8\}\to \text{H} & \{2,2,8,2,2\}\to \text{I} \\
>  \{2,2,2,8,7\}\to \text{J} & \{8,1,4,4,2,1\}\to \text{K} & \{8,8,1,1,1,1\}\to \text{L} \\
>  \{7,8,3,2,3,5,8\}\to \text{M} & \{8,3,2,2,8\}\to \text{N} & \{4,6,2,2,2,6,4\}\to \text{O} \\
>  \{8,2,2,2,3\}\to \text{P} & \{2,6,2,3,3,5,5\}\to \text{Q} & \{8,2,2,4,6,1\}\to \text{R} \\
>  \{3,3,3,3,4\}\to \text{S} & \{1,1,8,1,1,1\}\to \text{T} & \{7,1,1,1,7\}\to \text{U} \\
>  \{2,5,5,2,4,4,2\}\to \text{V} & \{4,8,3,2,4,4,8\}\to \text{W} & \{2,4,6,4,6,5,2\}\to \text{X} \\
>  \{1,3,2,5,2,3,1\}\to \text{Y} & \{2,4,4,3,3\}\to \text{Z} & \{2,2\}\to [ \\
>  \{1,4,3,3,3,1\}\to \backslash \texttt{"} & \{2,2\}\to ] & \{2,2,1,2,2\}\to {}^{\wedge} \\
>  \{1,1,1,1,1,1\}\to \_ & \{1,1\}\to \grave{ } & \{4,3,3,4,5\}\to \text{a} \\
>  \{9,2,2,2,5\}\to \text{b} & \{3,3,2,2,2\}\to \text{c} & \{4,2,2,2,9\}\to \text{d} \\
>  \{4,3,3,3,3\}\to \text{e} & \{1,1,7,9,2,2,1\}\to \text{f} & \{8,4,4,4,7,2\}\to \text{g} \\
>  \{9,1,1,1,6\}\to \text{h} & \{1,2,8,1,1\}\to \text{i} & \{2,2,2,10\}\to \text{j} \\
>  \{9,9,3,4,3,2\}\to \text{k} & \{1,2,9,1,1\}\to \text{l} & \{6,6,1,6,2,6,6\}\to \text{m} \\
>  \{6,2,1,1,6\}\to \text{n} & \{4,2,2,2,2\}\to \text{o} & \{9,3,2,2,5\}\to \text{p} \\
>  \{4,2,2,2,9\}\to \text{q} & \{6,6,1,1,2,1\}\to \text{r} & \{2,3,3,3,3\}\to \text{s} \\
>  \{1,7,3,2,2\}\to \text{t} & \{5,1,1,2,6\}\to \text{u} & \{1,3,3,2,4,3,1\}\to \text{v} \\
>  \{3,6,3,3,4,5,4\}\to \text{w} & \{2,4,2,4,4,2\}\to \text{x} & \{2,4,5,4,4,3,1\}\to \text{y} \\
>  \{2,3,3,3,2\}\to \text{z} & \{1,2,2,2\}\to \{ & \{10,10\}\to | \\
>  \{2,2,1\}\to \} & \{1,1,2,1,1,1\}\to \sim  & \text{} \\
> \end{array}
> }
> $

still to divide original binarized list to pieces to appy `newplib`, fortunately,there's vector column `{1,1,1,...,1}`

> [image]

**Update 2** extract chars

```
dv = Select[DeleteDuplicates@Transpose@lst2, Length[DeleteDuplicates@#] == 1 &];
divlst2 = Transpose /@ SequenceSplit[Transpose@lst2, dv];
ArrayPlot /@ divlst2 // Row[#, Spacer[20]] &
```

> [image]

then caculate `0`s of `divlst2`

```
zslst2 = Map[Count[#, 0] & /@ Transpose@# &, divlst2]
```

get

> {{9, 1, 1, 1, 6}, {4, 3, 3, 3, 3}, {2, 2, 9, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 9, 1, 
>         1}, {4, 2, 2, 2, 4}, {1, 4, 1}, {2, 5, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3}, {4, 2, 2, 2, 
>         4}, {6, 2, 1, 1, 2}, {2, 2, 9, 1, 1}, {4, 2, 2, 2, 9}}

then apply replacements

```
zslst2 /. newplib
```

> {"h", "e", {2, 2, 9, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 9, 1, 1}, {4, 2, 2, 2, 4}, ",", {2,
>      5, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3}, {4, 2, 2, 2, 4}, {6, 2, 1, 1, 2}, {2, 2, 9, 1, 
>     1}, "d"}

almoust close to the questions, maybe the function `Nearest` should be used...